# How to read in a txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read in from whats on the first two lines of a txt file, put it on a string and pass that string onto my methods. I'm confused on what I need to do in the main method.

Heres what I have:

```
    public class TestingClass  {
Stacked s;// = new Stacked(100);
 String Finame;

public TestingClass(Stacked stack) {
    //Stacked s = new Stacked(100);
    s = stack;
    getFileName();
    readFileContents(); 
}

public void readFileContents() {
    boolean looping;
    DataInputStream in;
    String line = "" ;
    int j, len;
    char ch;

    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(Finame));
        len = line.length();
        for(j = 0; j<len; j++) {
                System.out.println("line["+j+"] = "+line.charAt(j));
        }
    } 

    catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e);
    }
}   

public void getFileName() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter File Name");
    Finame = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You Entered " + Finame);
}

       public static void main(String[] args) {
         Stacked st = new Stacked(100);
         TestingClass clas = new TestingClass(st);
         //String y = new String("(z * j)/(b * 8) ^2");
         // clas.test(y);

       }
```

I tried String x = new String(x.getNewFile()) I'm not sure if thats the right way to go with that or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line1 = reader.readLine();
String line2 = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Should I do a try catch maybe?

Comment: you can surround with try/catch block to catch the I/O exception sure.  Or your method could have a throw for the exception.

Comment: I'm not getting any when i run it. To test it I passed line1 into a method clas.test(line1) ...Not getting any kind of output

Comment: Are you able to locate and open the file?

Comment: I just have a txt file created in elcipse. I have it working for one of my methods but not the first one I tried. thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

It's even easier in Java 1.5+. Use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Here's an [example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87). Essentially, it boils down to:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "MYFILE HERE";
    String line = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
      //first use a Scanner to get each line
      while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
        line = scanner.nextLine();
      }
    }
    finally {
      //ensure the underlying stream is always closed
      //this only has any effect if the item passed to the Scanner
      //constructor implements Closeable (which it does in this case).
      scanner.close();
    }
  }
```

...so there's really no reason for you to have a getFileContents() method. Just use Scanner.

Also, the entire program flow could use some restructuring.

- Don't declare a Stacked inside of your main method. It's likely
  that's what your testing class should *encapsulate*.

  Instead, write a private static String method to read the file name from the keyboard, then pass that to to your TestingClass object.
- Your TestingClass constructor should call a private method that opens
  that file, and reads in the first 2 (or however many else you end up
  wanting) lines into private class variables.
- Afterwards you can instantiate a new Stacked class.

For good *encapsulation* principles, have your TestClass provide public methods that the Driver program (the class with the *public static void main()* method can call to access the Stacked instance data without allowing access to the Stacked object directly (hence violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

Likely this advice will seem a little hazy right now, but get in the habit of doing this and in time you'll find yourself writing better programs than your peers.

Comment: In other words, you used the Scanner interface to read data from the console (System.in is an InputStream). You can use the same interface _in the same way_ to read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a txt file is usually pretty straightforward.

You should use a BufferedReader since you want the first two lines only.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
linecount = 0;
StringBuilder myline = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";

while ( (linecount < 2) && ((line = br.readLine()) != null) ) {
     myline.append(line);
     linecount++;
}

// now you have two lines in myline. close readers/streams etc
return myline.toString();
```

You should change your method signature to return the string. Now, you can say

```
String x = clas.getFileContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //read in local file:

> ```
> String content = "";
>         try {
>             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mVideoXmlPath));
>             do {
>                 String line;
>
>                 line = reader.readLine();
>
>                 if (line == null) {
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 content += line;
>             }
>             while (true);
>         }
>         catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

**check this :=)**